# Retrieving binary tree root data

Tags: c++, function

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Binary Tree Node
struct BTNode
{
    int data;
    BTNode *left;
    BTNode *right;
};

void fun(BTNode *iroot){
    iroot=new BTNode;
    iroot->data=2;
    iroot->left=NULL;
    iroot->right=NULL;
}

void main(){
    BTNode *root=NULL;
    
    fun(root);
    cout<<root->data;
    // Expexted Output is 2
    // Segmentation fault
}
```

In my opinion I have written perfect code.
But I know I definitely would have done something wrong.
As you are much more experienced in this field.
Please let me know my mistake.
Thank you big brother ❤️

Answer (score 3):

The argument `iroot` is a *copy of* what is passed, so modifying the argument in the callee function won't affect what is passed in caller. To have functions modify what is passed as arguments, you should add `&` to make the argument a reference.

```
void fun(BTNode *&iroot){ // add & to make a reference
    iroot=new BTNode;
    iroot->data=2;
    iroot->left=NULL;
    iroot->right=NULL;
}
```